# Copy multiple cells from two separate sheets based on input

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I have three sheets:

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

[image: Sheet 3]

I manually copy values from column A in Sheet 1 into column A in Sheet 3 and from Column A in Sheet 2 into Column B in Sheet 3 (as shown in the attached images).

The values are selected based on Column A and Column E. E.g. in Sheet 3, Q001-1 S1 from Sheet 1 is copied with G001-3 S3 and G002-2 S2.

I would like to simplify this process as much as possible because it is time consuming- however I cannot find a way to do this.

Is this even possible, using formulas or VBA??

Comment: How do you match which cell name belongs to which cell name between Sheet 1 and Sheet 2, what is the criteria?

Comment: @UmeshAgarwal there's no criteria, I make a plan and then copy the cells. e.g. Q001 S1 from Sheet 1 is related to G001 S1, S2 and G002 S2, etc.

Comment: There should be some criteria to automate the process, the relation between Col A of Sheet 1 and Col A of Sheet 2.

Comment: @UmeshAgarwal The relationship between Col A of Sheet 1 and Col A of Sheet 2 is based on my plan (which is based on the values in Col A and Col E of Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 i.e. Q001 ( Sheet 1, Col A) S1 (Sheet1, Col E) is can be related to G002 (Sheet 2, Col A) S1 and S3 (Sheet 2, Col E), which is different for each cell. I wonder if it is possible to have the plan in a different sheet which is then used to fill out Sheet 3?

Answer (score 1):

if i understood correctly you need to perform a join in Excel using the cell ID as a criteria.
I'd use Power Query instead of VBA because it's the tool made just for this kind of task:

1. Select the original table and format it as a table (Tab Home) -
   perform this operation for both data source
   [Format as a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhTp0.png)
2. Load both tables into PowerQuery (click on the table and then go to Data/Get and TrasformData and select From Table [PowerQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAIAs.png) repeat this step for both tables
3. From the table 1 select the tab Home select Merge, then choose the cell ID as a criteria (use the default left join) [Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlKUa.png)
4. Click on the new column to spread the data, remove uneccessary columns
5. Close and load (top left) your query into a new sheet (sheet3) - Load only the output table and not the original tables since they aren't necessary
6. To automate the process simply add new rows to the original tables and then click into the tab Data and then Refresh all. The results will appear into sheet3

I hope it helps!

Emanuele

Comment: The criteria is the `Sector` not the `Cell ID` if you carefully look at which data is actually matched.

Comment: Thanks, @Pᴇʜ is right. I've downloaded the adon and tried using it but will learn more about powe queries in order to see if will be able to produce what I want. It seems a bit complicated. Please take a look at the document attached, for a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17372Ptc20C1e148KsO6eDMzuqMtk9iwCNKE4dfWrnMk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks Peh for pointing that out. If you use Sector as a criteria for the join you need to be carefull since you could occur into a matrix multiplication since Sector appears multiple times into the colum you want to join to. Just be careful not to create unwated duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is arbitrary or based on criteria that can't be determined mathematically, it can't be solved with code alone. If you'd like to plan your arrangement on a 4th sheet, however, you can write conditional formulas in each cell on sheet 3 that evaluate your plan on sheet 4 and compare them to the cells containing the strings S1, S2, and S3. In cell A2 you could paste the following;

`=IF((EXACT(Sheet1!E2,Sheet4!A2)),Sheet1!A2,IF((EXACT(Sheet1!E3,Sheet4!A2)),Sheet1!A3,Sheet1!A4))`

It's evaluating the corresponding cell on sheet 4 for an S1 or S2, if it sees neither, it assumes S3. It then chooses the corresponding cell on sheet 1. The code in column B evaluates the corresponding cells on sheet 4 using the same trick;

`=IF((EXACT(Sheet2!E2,Sheet4!B2)),Sheet2!A2,IF((EXACT(Sheet2!E3,Sheet4!B2)),Sheet2!A3,Sheet2!A4))`

It then chooses the corresponding cell on sheet 2. You can drag these cells down as far as you need.

I wrote a working model and posted it to [GoogleDocs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Hf_rLiJp_M59Qw6IJa44rwLyNLccLS9mhG-LGRKCe4)

Comment: Thanks! This is the way I'm trying to do it, but I'm having trouble getting it output exactly what I want it to. Please take a look at the google doc file to see what I'm talking about, I've added a fifth sheet to explain my desired outcome. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17372Ptc20C1e148KsO6eDMzuqMtk9iwCNKE4dfWrnMk/edit?usp=sharing